# Table rendering issues using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm new to jQuery Mobile and I'm trying to render a table with headers in the left column and data on the right column, as demonstraded in jQuery Mobile docs [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/table/#entry-examples).

Here's my test code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
  <h1>Header</h1>
 </div>
 <div data-role="content">
  <ul class="subheader" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="d" data-inset="false">
   <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Section</li>
  </ul>
  <table data-role="table" data-mode="reflow">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Head 1</th>
     <th>Head 2</th>
     <th>Head 3</th>
     <th>Head 4</th>
     <th>Head 5</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Data 1</td>
     <td>Data 2</td>
     <td>Data 3</td>
     <td>Data 4</td>
     <td>Data 5</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here's as it's rendered on my desktop (Firefox, Mac OS X) - just as I want:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Ov4F5Gz.png]

And here's as it's rendered on my mobile device (PhoneGap, Samsung Galaxy S2):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5O6W.png]

Ermm, what happens? Shoudn't it render `<th>`'s on first column and `<td>`'s on second column? Why it didn't happen? What I've to change to accomplish that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: remove `data-mode="reflow"`, or your use break-points responsive CSS styles. http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/table-reflow/

Comment: Ermm, removing `data-mode="reflow"` didn't changed anything... My viewport settings was wrong, but even fixing them I didn't get reflow table, it's always tabular, no matter the `min-width` value I use in my responsive breakpoint. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I was missing HTML5 doctype on the document. Without the doctype, tables wasn't getting reflow style on PhoneGap's embedded browser.