# The table present different when the device's width is too small

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I create a table in jquery-mobile and the table present different from what I want it to be when the device's/screen's width is too small.

This is what I expect (when I open in web preview)

[image]

This is what it be in mobile simulator

[image]

I want each row represent in the same line
*[Position] [Level] [DeleteBtn]*
Not the seperate line
*[Position]

[Level]

[DeleteBtn]*

Thank you for suggestions or solutions.

Ps. I also want the *Damaged Position(s):* label to align the same horizontal position of the plus button. If you know the solution, it will be welcome. ;)

Comment: It would help to see some relevant code

Comment: @Ofir Here: http://jsfiddle.net/leaderdevil/m73fc/

Comment: Yeah, well, this looks well, doesn't it? I guess some other CSS or Javascript code makes it look different. Just for the sake of test, remove the css classes and html5 stuff (data-mode, data-role and data-priority) and check if it flows ok. Also, you can add all relevant code, so it would make more sense...

Comment: @Ofir I remove the stuff that you told me but it still show the same as 2nd image.

Comment: edited my answer with some more relevant links

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the "reflow" data-mode.
Check it out [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/table-reflow/).

If you want to keep it, you should make sure there is enough space for all columns (otherwise, it will break into a stacked presentation)

A similar question that might help: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986481/table-rendering-issues-using-jquery-mobile).

Also, according to [jquery](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/table-reflow/), reflow is the default, so removing it shouldn't help

Comment: My .html file already contains `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`. I will try to set the width of each column (in percent).

Comment: Please notice that HTML should be in lowercase in order to be valid xml (although it should also work as uppercase). check it out here: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-polyglot/#doctype

Comment: I change to `<!DOCTYPE html>` but it still the same.

Comment: Like I said, it should work eitherway but the lowercase is the better option. Regarding your problem, it's probably a width issue. You should look at the links I have provided and set a custom breakpoint for your table